# How to keep Hangfire job state between runs?

Tags: hangfire

I have an instance of a class running by **Hangfire** as a recurring job with a heavy constructor where all initialization happens. Then recurring job calls Execute method to make work done using instantiated stuff.

Is there a way to keep this class instance between executions and not initialize from scratch?

Comment: that's possible with the usage of a static method.

Comment: ... or with a Dependency Injection framework and a singleton binding

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire uses the `Activate` method to get an instance of your class, So if you bind your class as a singleton using a Dependency injection framework, you will able to use the same instance every time so the constructor will be called only once.

For example, in dotnet core you can bind your class in `startup` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
    ...
}
```